# (SOLVED) How many strings of length 10 either start with 11 or end with 100?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm somewhat floored as to what my professor is trying to ask here, i'm currently taking discrete mathematics and he gave the class this question for an upcoming exam. Can anybody offer an explanation?

(provided by my professor) the answer is : $ 2^8 $ + $ 2^7 $ $= 384$

i am aware my professor made a typo in the question and has also given an incorrect answer to the question he provided to the class.  I will have a discussion with him next class about this question.

Comment: Please, give us more information about the context of your question.

Comment: What is the mystery?  I assume we are speaking of binary strings...if the length were $3$ instead of $10$ the good strings would be $111,110,100$.  To warm up, count them by hand for lengths $4$ and $5$.  Note:  there is some ambiguity in the word "or".  I interpret it as one or the other, not excluding both.  Thus I'd say that $1100$ is a good string of length $4$.

Comment: That answer is wrong. That's the number of binary strings of length $10$ that start with $11$ plus the number of binary strings of length $10$ that end with $100$ -- the interaction isn't taken into account -- there are strings with both properties.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco i added the answer to the question in the post,  the word document our professor gave us came with an answer key attached,  that's about all the extra information i can give you.

Comment: Uh....  if that was given as the answer, transfer to another class. Now!

Comment: I echo the sentiment of the crowd:  if that's the official answer then there's a problem here.

Comment: It is a fake answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming he means binary strings (containing $1$ or $0$) then there are $2^{10}$ possible strings total (you have two choices for each character).  There are $2^{8}$ that start with $11$ (you have two choices for each of the remaining characters).  There are $2^{7}$ that end with $100$ (ditto) and $2^{5}$ that do both (still ditto).

So there are are $2^8 - 2^5$ that start with $11$ but do not end with $100$.  There are $2^7 - 2^5$ that end with $100$ but do not start with $11$. And there are $2^5$ that do both.

So together there are $2^8 + 2^7 - 2^5$ that do one or the other or both.

Comment: I assume he made a typo as well and meant to type bit strings,  thank you for your answer and clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Count the strings $11B^5 000$,...,$11B^5 110$, and $B^7100$.

This gives $2^5(2^3-1)+2^7$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b = a_1 \ldots a_{10}$ be a string of length 10 neither start with 11 nor end with 100. Suppose A is the set which is given by $A = \{b\}$. We shall find the cardinality |A| of A. Then, the answer of your question is $|2^{10}| - |A|$.  We compute |A| as follow. We have $a_1a_2 = 10, 01$ or 00 i.e, there are $2^2 -1$ ways.   Similary, there are $2^3  - 1 = 7$ ways for $a_8a_9a_{10}$.  Thus, $|A| = 3*2^5*8$. Therefore, the final answer is computed.

Answer (score 0):

A random string manages this with probability $1-\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{7}{8}=\frac{11}{32}$, making the answer $11\times 2^5=352$.